# Access VBA: Export table to Excel 2010 pivot table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-2010

I currently have the code below which saves two data tables into an Excel workbook on two separate sheets, and then opens the workbook:

```
Dim outputFileName As String
Dim outputFile As String
outputFile = "Export_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & Format(Time, "_hhmm") & ".xlsx"
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & outputFile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Callouts", outputFileName, True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Members", outputFileName, True

'Load Excel
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbkOutput = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(outputFileName)

'Show excel window
appExcel.Visible = True
```

I'd like to add some code to create a pivot table to display the data in excel but I'm unsure on how to do this - could anyone help please? :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "format the spreadsheet into a pivot table"? Do you want to *create* a pivot table based on a data table?

Comment: That is probably what I want to do but I may have the terminology wrong - essentially I'd like the code to run so that when excel opens, it shows the exported data in a pivot table. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, let me try another way: Do you want to *create* a pivot table based on the data you already have in your table, or do you want to format your data, cell by cell, to show something *like* a pivot table?

Comment: OK, having re-read the specification, I would like to create a pivot table based on the data that I already have in the table (sorry, I've never worked with pivot tables before and confused it with basic column sorting). I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample piece of code that creates a pivot table:

```
...
Dim aSheet as Worksheet
Set aSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                SourceData:="Sheet1!A1:D1000",
                                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=aSheet.Name&"!A1", _
                     TableName:="YourPivotTable", _
                     DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(aSheet.Name).Select
' Add the column field (the name of the pivot field is one of your data table) '
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("YourPivotTable").PivotFields("columnHeaderField")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
' Add the row field (the name of the pivot field is one of your data table) '
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("YourPivotTable").PivotFields("rowHeaderField")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
' Add the data field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("YourPivotTable")
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("aValueField"), "Sum of a value", xlSum
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("anotherValueField"), "Sum of another value", xlSum
End With
...
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am using this code, however nothing is happening, code runs successfully, Excel file is created successfully, but pivot is not made in the sheet. I am first populating the Source Data and then trying to make pivot table. The Source Data is created, but pivot is not created. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you finally find it out, however, in my code, if I use position and xlrow/column field nothing happens either.
I got rid off them and used only .orientation = 1 for xlcolumnfield, 2 for xlrowfield, 3 for filtering and 4 to AddDataField.
I didn't declare the position, the Excel itself adjust the position based on the order I wrote the code.
Said that, I'm instead stuck with the formula: I'm unable to change it from count to sum; I tried with just renaming the value and seems working, since in the field list it shows "Sum of..." but in the pivot itself I still get the count...